# Ball gets stuck when colliding with Rectangle

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, physics, bounding-box

A new problem i have at the moment is sometimes when the ball is bouncing around the screen, it may all of a sudden get stuck colliding with a rectangle, so it may hit a spot between the rectangle and the side of the screen. This sometimes results in either: a) the ball looks like it's shaking or something, which i am assuming as it's still colliding with the rectangle, it's velocity (as i have defined it) is constantly inversing... but it's still stuck... (that's what i cant solve... lol :( ), or b) when the ball collides with the rectangle, it starts to move along the edge of the rectangle and goes back and forth but it continues to do this... (so it's basically stuck moving just along the edge).

I have uploaded a video to youtube showing this in action (btw... the ball gets stuck and goes up and down the right side of the screen and then starts going along the top edge of the white rectangle and then eventually bounces off into oblivion... well basically frees itself, which is kind of ok but then if you wait 5 more seconds, it repeats this process)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qfpgtoWbIU&feature=youtu.be

the code i am using for collision detection with the rectangle is:

```
if (theBall.GetRectangle.Bottom >= cornerSquare.GetRectangle.Top && theBall.GetRectangle.Bottom <= cornerSquare.GetRectangle.Bottom)
{
    theBall.pVelocity.Y = -theBall.pVelocity.Y;
}
```

thats for detection if the ball hit's the top of the rectangle.

detection with the right side of the screen is:

```
if (pPosition.X + pTexture.Width >= screenWidth)
{
    pVelocity.X = -pVelocity.X;
}
```

I hope someone has a simple and effective solution to this as i just want to 'be done' with all this collision detection nonsense lol... as it's taking up most of my time whilst i could be alot more productive doing other parts of the game.

Thanks for reading, taking the time to read, taking the time to help.... ETC.... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check for collision first using a calculated test-rectangle.

For example the ball moves for Vector2(1, 1) per Update. Find out where the Rectangle for collision WOULD be at the next step BEFORE moving.

```
int nextPosX = currRect.X + (int)movementVector.X;
int nextPosY = currRect.Y + (int)movementVector.Y;

// find out where the rectangle would be after this update:
Rectangle nextStepsCollisionRect = new Rectangle(nextPosX, nextPosY, width, height);

// check if the test rectangle would collide:
if( collisionTest(nextStepsCollisionRect, sideWall) )
{
    // do not move the intended way!
    // invert X and recalc with pre-calculated rectangle again...
} else {
    // no collision. now move the caculated way:
    ball.CollisionRectangle = nextStepsCollisionRect;
}
```

This is a quite simple way. Use "ray tracing" if the ball is a very fast bullet (just to be mentioned).

Comment: cool, this sounds promising. If i change the direction if the ball is going to get stuck or collide with the wall, then will it still look fairly realistic? I suppose if it's only 1 frame later then i shouldn't matter. I will try this and let you know how it goes. Thanks :)

Comment: Hehe, no problem. It's a very common solution for this problem so i would wonder if it does not work. There is a small  chance that the ball is bouncing multiple times in the cornors. Works the same way - it's just a bit more tricky to code ;)

Comment: Hey, i am going to confirm your solution/answer as the best, as i have tested it using your solution above several times and then using original solution and this seems to work, as the ball isnt getting stuck (so far as i have noticed when testing via new/your solution) on the corners of the rectangles and it's also not stuck moving along the perimeter of the rectangle and edge of the screen. Thanks very very much for this. This has really driven me mad trying to find a solution and trying different things... :)

Comment: Hehe, no problem! I really like to answer Questions like this. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your ball is stuck along the edge you can simply bring the ball position to its previuos position before the collision (the one it had in the previous frame), in this way you change its velocity and ensure that the ball is not colliding anymore, this should do the trick.
You can achieve this by subtracting ball speed to ball position.

Comment: thanks for the reply pinckerman. So how would i go about finding out if the ball is 'stuck', as oppose to have just collided with the rectangle? I mean i can check if it's collided with the rectangle but then do i check if it's collided again with the rectangle, as i am assuming it's collided twice or more with the rectangle and thats why it looks like it's shaking, so it's direction is inversing...? thanks

Comment: The first time you detect a collision you act like I've explained, in that way you should avoid that stuck situation. You subtract the speed first and then you invert the velocity as you need.